# SAML 2.0 Endpoint (HTTP) giving 500 Internal Server error in onelogin

Tags: saml-2.0, onelogin

I have created a **SAML Test Connector(SP)** in **OneLogin** portal. It generated a **SAML 2.0 Endpoint (HTTP)** url in the SSO Tab. When I try to open the end point url it is giving me a 500 error. But if I am adding some existing apps from onelogin portal (For Eg. salesforce or aws) and copy the generated URL it is taking me to their login page. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the SAML Test Connector(SP) you may access to the "configuration" tab and provide the SP ACS URL endpoint, if not the IdP (Onelogin) doesn't know where to send the SAMLResponse when you initiate a IdP-initiated SSO.

Other connectors as Salesforce or AWS has pre-configured ACS endpoint (since we know where those services expect the SAMLResponse).

Comment: I have given wrong value in ACS (Consumer) URL Validator* . Now I gave it as ^ and it works fine

Comment: Thanks i was facing the same problem because `For now, set ACS (Consumer) URL Validator to .*` in OneLogin tutorial's